# Change of basis matrix from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ or from $\beta$ to $\alpha$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, terminology, change-of-basis

In Peterson and Sochacki's *Linear Algebra and Differential Equations* they define (in section 5.3) the change of basis matrix from $\alpha$ to $\beta$, $[I]_{\beta}^{\alpha}$, as the matrix whose columns are the $\alpha$-coordinates of the $\beta$ vectors. This matrix transforms $\beta$-coordinates into $\alpha$ coordinates so I think it should be called the change of basis matrix from $\beta$ to $\alpha$.

Is there a good reason to call it the change of basis matrix from $\alpha$ to $\beta$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordered bases of a finite dimensional vector space $V$,  then in my mind the change of basis matrix from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ is defined to be the matrix $M$ that satisfies $M [x]_\alpha = [x]_\beta$ for all $x \in V$. I think many linear algebra books use this or an equivalent definition. (Here $[x]_\alpha$ is the coordinate vector of $x$ with respect to $\alpha$.)

Comment: I think that Definition 2 in these notes is very standard: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/CoordinateChange.pdf

Comment: @littleO That's the definition I'm used to. I'm wondering if the authors might have a good reason for naming it as they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an excellent reason: you can obtain the matrix $A'$ of the associated linear map in basis $\beta$ from the matrix $A$ of this linear map in basis $\alpha$.

Indeed, let's denote $X, Y,\dots$ the column matrix of vectors in basis $\alpha$ and $X', Y',\dots,\:$ their column matrix in basis $\beta$. If $Y $ is the column matrix of coordinates of the image of a vector with column vector of coordinates $X$ in basis $\alpha$, we have the relation
$$Y=AX.\tag1$$
Now, denoting $P$ the change of basis matrix, the column matrices of the same vectors, in bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linked through the relations
$$X=PY',\qquad Y=PY',$$
so that $(1)$ can be written as
$$PY'=A(PX')\iff Y'=P^{-1}A(PX')$$
which shows that the matrix of the linear map in basis $\beta$ has become
$$A'= P^{-1}AP.$$

Comment: Thanks. I guess the last $P'$ should be an $A'$? And what's a "column matrix of vectors"?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. Thank you for pointing it!  For the last expression, I mean the representation of a vector by the column matrix of its coordinates in a basis. I made the ellipsis of ‘coordinates’  to shorten a bit my phrasing.

Comment: This is a good reason, thank you. In summary: Let $A$ be the matrix for some linear transformation $T$ with respect to $\alpha$ and $A'$ the matrix for $T$ with respect to $\beta$. The change of basis matrix in question, let's call it $P$, can  be viewed as taking something "from $\alpha$ to $\beta$" because of the relationship $A' = P^{-1}AP$. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly${}$.

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be that "coordinates" are duals to "vectors" themselves.

While the matrix transforms $\beta$-coordinates into $\alpha$-coordinates, it transforms $\alpha$-vectors to $\beta$-vectors via
$$
(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n) = (\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n) [I].
$$